# GAE channel api parsing onmessage

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-app-engine, channel-api

I am building an app with gae, and using the channel api.

```
String message ="<data><title>newMessage</title><message>Hello</message></data>"; 
channelService.sendMessage(new ChannelMessage(user,message));
```

This string is sent from the java servlet, and on the front end i want to parse it with jquery. This is what i did, but it doesn't work.

```
function onSocketMessage(message) {

     var xml = $.parseXML(message.data),
     $xml = $( xml ),
     $title = $xml.find('title');

    if($title == "newMessage"){

           alert($xml.find('message'));
    }
}
```

This is the javascript code which actually works fine.

```
var messageXML = ((new DOMParser()).parseFromString(message.data, "text/xml"));
    var title = messageXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    if(title == "newMessage"){
        alert(messageXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("message")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
```

Comment: No output? Do you receive an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSocketMessage(message) {

    var xml = $.parseXML(message.data),
    $xml = $( xml ),
    $title = $xml.find('title');

    if($title.text() == "newMessage"){
        alert($xml.find('message'));
    }
}
```

You should be giving `.text()`, I guess you missed that in this line `if($title.text() == "newMessage")`.